# How to choose or design a suitable single board computer (SBC)?

Tags: embedded, design, computers, sbc

Programmer here, making my first foray into anything hardware-specific.

I need to deploy my software on dedicated hardware to around 1000 sites as part of a research project. The hardware is required to:

- Run a local, lightweight web-application.
- Push data over the internet to our central server.
- Monitor a set of 5 local sensors.
- Have Ethernet access to the local network.

Currently this runs fine on 1 remote site on a RaspberryPi 3, interfacing with our central server. Checking remotely, I can see that typically around 330-350MB of memory is used (`free -m`). `top -i` shows typical usage of between 1.0-10%. I am not keen on deploying this to 1000 separate Pis, but I am having difficulty researching information about choosing the correct alternatives for me.

1. Are there any good commands or tools that can provide me a better understanding of how much/what RAM/CPU/etc my software requires?
2. Is it worth considering designing a custom SBC?
3. Assuming I am buying a cheap SBC or hiring an engineer to design a suitable one, what information do I need to do write a good specification for this?

Comment: What's your maximum budget per device? Is wired Ethernet a hard requirement (nowadays WiFi is a lot cheaper)? What's the actual problem with deploying to 1000 Pis?

Comment: @nekomatic
Max budget: £5-15, but pretty flexible (this is part of a research grant)
Ethernet is a hard requirement.
My team-lead would prefer we do not use Pis as the research will probably be spun into the commercial sector, so the RPi foundation would not support subsequent orders.

Comment: Also, how are the sensors interfaced to the Pi at the moment, and what language is the current software written in?

Comment: @nekomatic I've not personally worked on the sensors, I think it's just a small microprocessor hat connected to the GPIO pins. Software is a mixture of Java (Springboot for the backend) and JavaScript (React for the frontend), with a little bit of Python/Bash scripting too.

Comment: Very hard to find a computer capable of running Java and a webserver with ethernet for less than the price of a Pi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given you have a prototype running successfully on a Pi 3, I think you have three options:

1. Deploy the same setup on Raspberry Pis, for the lowest cost you can achieve,

   1a. Find an alternative single-board computer that runs Linux, which should run your existing software with little modification, or
2. Identify a lower-cost hardware platform that has the features you need and reengineer the software to fit the constraints of this hardware.

You mention a budget of £15 per device. I'm not that familiar with how costs work at this sort of volume but I think you should be able to set up a Pi Zero with a microSD card, power supply, some sort of case and a USB-Ethernet adapter for not too far off this amount. If you already have a Pi hat design for the sensors, talk to a hardware design company (or in-house resource) about how to reproduce the same thing at your volume and what that would cost.

Given what you've already said about the memory and CPU load on a Pi 3 I don't see why a Pi Zero shouldn't work, but if you need to know how to get more specific data then I think that's a question for elsewhere, maybe [Unix and Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) for monitoring resources used by a process or Stack Overflow for how to profile code in the specific languages you have used.

If you can't get an actual Pi device in quantity that suits your needs, there are other single-board devices around that can run Linux and to which you should be able to port your software and adapt your sensor interface - search for *linux sbc* or try [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_single-board_computers) for information (so much information!). Compared to the Pi this may save you money at the cost of less certainty of supply and support. A left-field option could be to find a cheap wireless router, which is basically an embedded PC with at least one Ethernet port, and get your software running on it via a modification of something like [OpenWRT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenWrt) or [DD-WRT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DD-WRT) - you'd have to figure out how to do the hardware interfacing bit though.

For option 2, you are looking at a microcontroller development board that supports Ethernet, perhaps from a manufacturer like ST, NXP or Microchip. You might find one with the Ethernet connector on board or you might need to add this separately. Then you need to rewrite your software to run on the microcontroller, probably in C, and either with or without a real-time operating system (RTOS). You'd need to talk to an embedded software developer to figure out what the minimum requirements for speed and RAM are going to be given what your software actually needs to do, with specifics of how large the data is, how frequent the requests to the web server will be, and so on. I'm not an expert but my gut feeling is that starting down this path will very quickly eat up any saving you might be able to gain over the cost of the Pi-based system.

Comment: I am pretty confident that the RPi 0 is only available in single orders, whilst the commercial Computer Module is overkill (and so too expensive) for this project.

Comment: At this quantity I would definitely get in touch with the RPi foundation to discuss the lowest cost option available to you. What do you expect the selling price of the product to be? If it meets an important need that customers will pay for you can afford the few quid to swap to a different Pi; if it's going to be a low-margin mass-market device then the investment in reengineering on a cheaper platform can be done at that point. Keep the requirements for your current study distinct from the requirements for future commercialisation.

Comment: You make a very valid point, we can definitely create a suitable product for our initial research and the commercial considerations of my supervisor can be discussed in the future.

Comment: See my edit for another option.

Comment: While OpenWRT can run on larger systems, it's associated with things that wouldn't have enough memory for the asker's apparent need.  And MCU solutions are out by orders of magnitude!

Comment: One more edit re where to ask about profiling resource usage.

Answer (score 4):

1. A good profiling of your software should give you the requirements memory and CPU-wise, but I am no software expert.
2. No, there is no way your small volume is going to justify the cost of the hundreds of engineering hours needed to design a SBC from scratch.

What you should consider is designing a slave pcb to be connected to your SBC, that will handle all the connections to your sensors. Such PCBs are much simpler, and can be manufactured & tested externally.

Additionally, a staged deployment could help you identify potential issues before going full-scale, and implement some kind of status monitoring to make sure everything is running smoothly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Checking with others in the team, we should be able to implement your slave PCB suggestion. To the first point, how does one do a significant profile of the software as it relates to hardware?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Sclrx's suggestion to use slave modules for the sensor interfacing.

I'd like to suggest that you look into  wireless communication to create a network, where a number of slave modules communicate to an SBC, which in turn pushes data over the internet to your server. You could have just a few SBCs receiving sensor data from a number of locations, and this will reduce your total system cost.

You could use 2.4GHz nRF transceivers, LoRA modules, or even Wi-Fi modules if the range is small enough for your scenario.

Edit: take a look at [this site](https://lastminuteengineers.com/nrf24l01-arduino-wireless-communication) for an explanation of nRF transceivers.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll look into your suggestions about the slave modules. Do you have any further suggestions about actually specifying the central SBC?

Comment: @saeched Designing a custom SBC from scratch for this application is, in my opinion, overkill. There are a number of SBCs out there catering to various requirements (RasPis and a plethora of copycat Pis, BeagleBones, LattePanda, TinkerBoard, the list goes on). You may want to thoroughly vet these options before you consider designing a custom SBC.

Comment: Yeah I am definitely leaning that way from these replies. The concern with SBCs such as the RPi is that we are paying for capacity we do not need and may struggle in sourcing at sufficient scale in the future.

Comment: If your major worry is the wasted resources on an SBC, why not downgrade to a network-enabled microcontroller platform instead? Even the Arduino Uno has a Ethernet add-on, and this is true for some of the more powerful MCUs as well. The drawback is, of course, you would have to redevelop your already working system on that particular MCU platform.

Comment: An MCU wouldn't meet the asker's memory need by several orders of magnitude.  Network connected MCU's are pretty much *a bad idea* until you get to things like the ESP's and high end Cortex M4, as really on the former is cost effective.  But again, _none_ of these have the needed memory, and adding that in a custom way would destroy the project budget.

Comment: @ChrisStratton the ESP is actually a humble little thing compared to the more powerful Cortex M4. Also, if you think the asker needs 300MB of memory to accomplish the same task on an MCU, you'd be sorely wrong. That 300MB figure is due to the various background processes running on the RPi, which will not be the case on an MCU. I'm pretty confident an IoT enabled MCU will be able to meet the asker's requirements, because I myself am currently working on a distributed sensor system using the ESP8266.

Comment: For the sensors, sure, but you missed the "Run a local, lightweight web-application." part of the problem.  Also Ethernet on MCUs rarely makes sense.  If the tasks can be reduced, then the wired Ethernet could point to something like an MT7688 or AR9331 OpenWRT router chip (ignore the wifi, just hook up a magjack) - that's likely to come in _cheaper_ than a Cortex M4 Ethernet solution, and it lets you use standard network APIs and tools rather than having to fight with something like WICED.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it worth considering designing a custom SBC?

Absolutely yes. The time and labor you'll save by having a single assembly that is mostly machine assembled will be enormous.

At minimum, you should make a custom sensor integration board that mates with a COTS processing module, such as a Pi Zero or equivalent.

> Assuming I am buying a cheap SBC or hiring an engineer to design a suitable one, what information do I need to do write a good specification for this?

You need to provide complete details on:

- the sensors you're using and the data you want from them (including sample rates)
- the network interface to the central server, including all of the protocols you want supported (e.g., TCP/IP, NTP, HTTP(S), SNMP, etc.)
- any processing of the data that occurs locally in the SBC
- the environment in which the SBC needs to operate, including power supply

Comment: As a consulting engineer, what do you look for when approached by a client such as ourselves? I would like to provide the clearest specification possible, so learning how to test my software's requirements before approaching an engineer would be useful.

Comment: That is in fact what I do, and what I wrote above is exactly what I would want to see. Very often, the first phase of my relationship with a new client is helping them to write a good functional specification.